# What software to use for psychology questionnaire?

Tags: social-psychology, measurement, methodology, survey

I'm doing a schoolwork about Spiral Dynamics and last part is doing practical research and everything is completed except we yet didnt found any digital platform with which we can conduct our research..,

I would love to hear your recommendations because we are little bit lost with this part of project (still noobies).

Answer (score 3):

One that I used at my university is [Qualtrics](https://www.qualtrics.com/). It was under the university's license, so I don't know what the costs are for single users. Qualtrics allows you to ask many different types of questions (open ended, likert, option select and more) and can easily export the data to excel files for further processing.

[Survey Monkey](https://nl.surveymonkey.com/) is another tool that is often used. Basic functions can be used for free, but for more powerful tools you'll need to pay.

Finally, I know of [Google Form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/). Afaik it can be used for free, but I am unaware of their privacy policies (Google tends to collect a lot of data).

Answer (score 1):

**Limesurvey:** Just to add to Robin Kramer's answer - a very useful platform is the fully open source [Limesurvey](https://www.limesurvey.org/). It runs on PHP and, in my opinion, has better capabilities than Surveymonkey plus you fully control it. You can easily install it on your web server, or you can use many hosting solutions that will offer automated LS installations (I know for sure of Siteground and A2 hosting). If you want this to be fully in your control - install it on a dedicated server in your network. To test out - you can install it on your laptop. It has extensive manual and very good user community on Limesurvey forums. It is widely used in universities and commercially.

If you want to use their one-click "comfort-update" you will need to pay something like 78 EUR per year, but you can also do updates manually (that can be a bit cumbersome if you are unfamiliar with simple web server concepts). I have been a bit lazy and update maybe a couple of times  a year.

One of the best parts about it is the **ease of getting data** - whatever format you like, you have it - CSV, SPSS, R and others. If you want to download PDF summaries you can do that too, however these ready made reporting systems are rather poor anywhere - a much better solution is to download pure data, analyze and visualize as you want.

It has an RPC interface that you can use to automate control and getting data from your surveys. I use R a lot and there is a great library at GitHub https://github.com/cloudyr/limer that allows me to just get data instantly from Limesurvey server (about 10 seconds for 10000 rows) and use for automated analysis and visualization that I have defined in R.

If you start trying it out and get stuck, just give me a shout.